How to load multiple .mat files with different suffix once I selected a starting file?
I have the following problem which I do not know how to approach:
I have a folder with four .mat files like this:
LeCroy000_000_ch1.mat
LeCroy000_000_ch2.mat
LeCroy000_001_ch1.mat
LeCroy000_001_ch2.mat
I want to load the 1st file 'LeCroy000_000_ch1.mat' and then I need two 'for' to iterate:

first between channels 'ch1' to 'ch2'
then between measurements '000' to '001'

My code:
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import filedialog as fd  
from pathlib import Path  
import os  
import scipy.io  
   

class Program:
    
    def __init__(self, argument_1):
        # Initializing main window 
        Main.resizable(0,0)
        Main.geometry("300x150")
        Main.title("Demo")

    # Creating Canvas on top of main window
        Canvas_One = Canvas(Main, width=300, height=150, bg='#%02x%02x%02x' % (240, 240, 240))
        Canvas_One.place(x=0, y=0)

        # Creating button
        Demo_button = Button(Canvas_One, text="Extract data", width=10, heigh=2,command=self.load_files)
        Demo_button.place(anchor='nw',x=10, y=10)
        
    def load_files(self):
        # Browsing the .mat file
        self.open_files =fd.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Matlab Workspace", "*.mat")])
        # Getting the filename + extension
        file = Path(self.open_files)
        # Getting file's directory
        modelRelPath = Path(self.open_files).parent

        # Here I am lost
        file_change = file.split('_')]

        # Function
        self.extract_data()

    def extract_data(self):
        # first for measurements iteration
        for i in range(2):
                # 2nd for channels iteration
                for j in range(2):
                        obj_mat= scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),modelRelPath, file_change)))
    
        

Main = Tk()
Program(Main)
Main.mainloop()


have you tried sorting the files using an custom key?

You can e. g. build the filename out of i and j using a so-called f-string.

I am sorry guys, I am lost. I have a really hard time trying to finish my task which involves loading 1st file and then going through all the files in the folder...
